Adding Exchange Rate into Excel Spreadsheet with Pre-Existing Formulas
I am sure this is a simple one, but I am trying to add a calculation to a cell to compensate for that days exchange rate.  This is for an travel expense report spreadsheet given to me by my company, so they already had formulas in place.  Basically, I need to divide the total of all cells listed by the exchange rate, but I am unable to make it work.
For this instance:
H17 is the foreign currency amount
P17 is the "Total" cell that I am trying to modify
Q17 is the exchange rate cell
This is the pre-existing formula in the "Total" cell:
=IF(SUM(G17,H17,J17:N17)=0,0,SUM(G17,H17,J17:N17)-O17)

Thanks in advance!
Here is a sample of the table I am working with to hopefully help visualize things better:
| -- | -------- | ----------------- | --------------------- | ------------- | ----- | ----------------- | ----- | ----------------- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ------------- | -----  | --------- | --------------------- |
| -- |   B      |        C          |          D            |       E       |   F   |        G          |   H   |     I    |   J    |   K   |   L   |   M   |   N   |       O       |    P   |     Q     |         R             |
| -- | -------- | ----------------- | --------------------- | ------------- | ----- | ----------------- | ----- | ----------------- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ------------- | -----  | --------- | --------------------- |
| 14 | Date     |  Contract Number  | Primary destination   | Description   | CC    | Airfare / Train   | Hotel | Mileage           | Fuel  | Meals | Taxi  | Misc  | Unallowable   | TOTAL  | X-Rate    | Paid by Company Card  |
|    |          |                   |                       |               |       |                   |       | (Miles)    (Amt)  |       |       |       |       |               |        |           |                       |
| -- | -------- | ----------------- | --------------------- | ------------- | ----- | ----------------- | ----- | ----------------- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ------------- | -----  | --------- | --------------------- |
| 15 | 09/11/24 | 1234567890123456  | Some Country          | Uber          |   N   |                   |       |          |        |       |       | 36.15 |       |               | 36.15  |     0     |                       |
| -- | -------- | ----------------- | --------------------- | ------------- | ----- | ----------------- | ----- | ----------------- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ------------- | -----  | --------- | --------------------- |
| 16 | 09/11/24 | 1234567890123456  | Some Country          | Flight        |   N   |       1,000       |       |          |        |       |       |       |       |               | 1,000  |     0     |                       |
| -- | -------- | ----------------- | --------------------- | ------------- | ----- | ----------------- | ----- | ----------------- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ------------- | -----  | --------- | --------------------- |
| 17 | 09/11/24 | 1234567890123456  | Some Country          | Hotel         |   N   |                   |  900  |          |        |       |       |       |       |               |  300   |   3.00    |                       |
| -- | -------- | ----------------- | --------------------- | ------------- | ----- | ----------------- | ----- | ----------------- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ------------- | -----  | --------- | --------------------- |


If you need to divide, why are you subtracting instead? And why does your text say Q17, but the formula use O17? Columns Q and O aren't even close to each other.

@KenWhite, Thank you for your reply.  I added a table to my original post to help clear things up:
H17 is the foreign amount that I need to convert
P17 is the expected result where the sample formula sits
Q17 is the exchange rate
Please let me know if you have any more questions.

Your sample data is confusing when compared to your text. You say H17 is the foreign currency amount, but the heading for that column says Hotel. You say that you are trying to modify Q17, but that column is headed X-Rate, which would appear to be the exchange rate. So what you describe isn't logical. You should be applying the exchange rate  (Q) to the total in column P if Q is not equal to zero, and that should be going in a new column, not Q (which contains the rate of exchange).

H17 specifically is the cost of the Hotel in foreign currency, not USD.  The formula I am trying to modify sits in P17.  The original formula SUMs (G, H, J:N) then subtracts "O" if anything exists in there.  In it's current configuration would have "900" in P17.  What I am trying to do is divide the total of P17 by what is entered into Q17.  Essentially, I need to add "/Q17" to the final answer of the formula in P17 so that P17 will show the "Total" cost in USD, not the foreign currency amount.  Does that help at all?

So just add it. =IF(SUM(G17,H17,J17:N17)=0,0,(SUM(G17,H17,J17:N17)-O17)/Q17).

Well, I thought I tried that, but I guess I didn't try wrapping only the 2nd SUM.  That fixed it for the cells that need converting, thank you for that.  I knew it had to be simple.  Thank you!!!

I've written an answer. Your final explanation in the comments finally cleared things up for me so that I understood what you were trying to do. :-)

Just add the division to the end. You'll need to wrap the entire SUM operation and the subtraction in parentheses, because the division won't be done in the order you want without them - the division would be done before the subtraction because of operator precedence.
=IF(SUM(G17,H17,J17:N17)=0,0,(SUM(G17,H17,J17:N17)-O17)/Q17)

